# wordpress add payment system. Where to handle form

Tags: wordpress

I wanna to add payment to wordpress . Payment system called PayBox. https://paybox.money/docs/ru/pay-in/3.3#tag/Inicializaciya-cherez-brauzer-polzovatelya/paths/~1payment.php/get . I trying to create form and send data with post method to php file and send request to payment with code below.

```
<?php
                $request = [
                'pg_merchant_id'=> 111,
                'pg_amount' => 25,
                'pg_salt' => 'some_random_string',
                'pg_order_id'=>'123',
                'pg_description' => 'Описание заказа',
                'pg_result_url' => 'https://example.com'
                ];

                // $request['pg_testing_mode'] = 1; //add this parameter to request for testing payments

                //if you pass any of your parameters, which you want to get back after the payment, then add them. For example:
                // $request['client_name'] = 'My Name';
                // $request['client_address'] = 'Earth Planet';

                //generate a signature and add it to the array
                ksort($request); //sort alphabetically
                array_unshift($request, 'payment.php');
                array_push($request, 'secret_key'); //add your secret key (you can take it in your personal cabinet on paybox system)

                $request['pg_sig'] = md5(implode(';', $request));

                unset($request[0], $request[1]);

                $query = http_build_query($request);
                //redirect a customer to payment page
                header('Location:http://core.local/payment.php?'.$query);
```

But problem is . Where can I handle this code?  I dont know how to do this in wp. Form created with page builder .

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out with your page builder that creates the form if they are able to handle hooks. See if there's a function you can hook into when the form is processed.

Generally this would go in your functions.php file of your theme (or a child theme if you're using a ready-made theme).